# Load function in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming

Ok, First of all I'm totally newbie in Haskell, so please be kind.

I have done a simple program that open a file by its name. Here is what I have done so far:

```
import System.IO  

main = do  
    myFileName <- getLine
    contents <- readFile myFileName  
    putStr contents
```

All is working pretty well, but I want to create a function, that to do the same thing and call it in main.
I want to accomplish something like this:

```
main myFunc

myFunc x = do  
        myFileName <- getLine
        contents <- readFile myFileName  
        putStr contents
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `main = myFunc` should do it if you get rid of the unused argument to `myFunc`.  If you actually use that argument for something then `main = myFunc <arg-goes-here>`

Comment: `myFunc` is a bit of a questionable name for the new entity, though -- it's not a function! How about `printUserSpecifiedFile` or something else descriptive?

Comment: I'd like to give you a little advice, given that you're new to Haskell: If you start your program with reading data from disk, you'll be inclined to write everything in IO. It's a better plan to write two lots of example data into your source code, and write functions to manipulate that, then add the IO at the end. That will help you keep your code as pure as possible. (Using two sets of data stops you from trying to write everything as constants, helping you to think in terms of functions all the time.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it looks like all you have to do is something like this:

```
import System.IO  

myFunc = do  
        myFileName <- getLine
        contents <- readFile myFileName  
        putStr contents

main = myFunc
```

You were very close.

When Haskell is run from the terminal, it looks for `main` as the entry point of your application. In this case, when running from the terminal, a common `main` would simply be a function that does some print-like operation (as `myFunc` does).